# Dynamic thenReturn()-Statements in Mockito

Tags: java

id like to have a method that can dynamically create Mock objects of a certain class.

```
static Scanner mockScanner(int personsEntering, int personsLeaving) {
        Scanner scanner = mock(Scanner.class);

        when(scanner.readyToProcessPerson()).thenReturn(true);

        when(scanner.personWantsToEnter()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
        return scanner;
}
```

The method personWantsToEnter() in Scanner returns true or false depending on wether a persons wants to enter or leave.
I want my method mockScanner() return a mock-object that simulates persons entering and leaving depending on the parameters 'personsEntering' and 'personsLeaving'. (For example: when 'personsEntering' is 2 and 'personsLeaving' is 1, the mock-object should behave like it is shown in the code-example above.)
Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: `Scanner` is your own class and not the `java.util.Scanner` class?

Comment: Yeah, its my own class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273). What exactly is the problem you have? Currently you are not using the `personsEntering` and `personsLeaving` arguments. Also it is not clear how these arguments are related to the desired return values of `readyToProcessPerson()` and `personWantsToEnter()`.

Comment: I am sorry for asking my question poorly. I want the personEntering and personLeaving arguments to determine how many times the method personWantsToEnter() returns true, and how many times it returns false. If personEntering is 4, personWantsToEnter() should return true the first four times it is invoked. If personLeaving is 2 in this example, personWantsToEnter() should return false the 5th and 6th time it is invoked. I hope that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `thenReturn()` dynamically within a `for()` loop, depending on the given arguments `personsEntering` and `personsLeaving`. Each time you have to update the `OngoingStubbing<Boolean>` variable you get from the `when()` method. Your code might look like this:

```
public static Foobar mockFoobar(int personsEntering, int personsLeaving) {
    Foobar f = Mockito.mock(Foobar.class);
    
    OngoingStubbing<Boolean> stub = Mockito.when(f.personWantsToEnter());
    
    for (int i=0; i<personsEntering; i++) {
        stub = stub.thenReturn(true);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<personsLeaving; i++) {
        stub = stub.thenReturn(false);
    }
    return f;
}
```

*(I replaced `Scanner` with `Foobar` to avoid confusions with `java.util.Scanner`)*

See the following unit test which will pass based on the given call of `mockFoobar()`:

```
@Test
void test() throws Exception {
    Foobar test = mockFoobar(4, 2);
    Assertions.assertTrue(test.personWantsToEnter());
    Assertions.assertTrue(test.personWantsToEnter());
    Assertions.assertTrue(test.personWantsToEnter());
    Assertions.assertTrue(test.personWantsToEnter());
    Assertions.assertFalse(test.personWantsToEnter());
    Assertions.assertFalse(test.personWantsToEnter());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I was looking for.